# Is there an encoding difference between Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost, udp, boost-asio

This is related to: [Sending packets over UDP from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620020/sending-packets-over-udp-from-windows)

I making simple UDP client using Boost ASIO. When I run the client on Ubuntu, it can send to the server (listener) the data correctly. However, when I am running it on Windows, the server can not parse the data correctly.

Since I do not have access to the server code. I can not be sure what is happening there.

I am sure that it is not Networking (such as firewall) problem because I tried the code on Ubuntu VM inside a Windows Host and it worked.

My question is: Should I encode the message I sent from Windows in different manner? (I am not sure but something like UTF-8, UTF-16 differences.. maybe..)

The sending code:

```
socket_.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message, sizeof(*message)), endpoint_);
```

Where `message` is pointer to some struct that the server expecting. `end_point_` is correct. I printed it and the address and port are correct.

Comment: "when I am running it on Windows, the server can not parse the data correctly." What do you mean by that? In what way is the data corrupted? What kind of data are we talking about?

Comment: You could use a network sniffer like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) and compare the packets you send from a windows machine and a linux machine.

Comment: @Jodocus I am sending a MAVLINK message. I mean that the server is not responding cirrectly to the message (for example I sent a "Power ON" message but it did not Power On anything)

Comment: @mkaes I will do.. thnaks for suggestion

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Is the endianess difference between Windows and Ubuntu an issue?

Comment: @Jodocus I did not thought of that. The MAVLINK parsing mechanism is byte by byte and not bit by bit.. In this case, would the endianess of the OS affect the process (Sorry if my comment is non-logical cause I do not have any experience in this field)

Comment: @HumamHelfawi It's is the architecture of the computer; not the OS that decides the endian-ness.  If the chips of both machines are intel based then there will not be any difference.  In addition, bits are not the smallest unit available as a general rule; but bytes.  ie the distance between the pointer 0x01 and 0x02 is one byte; not one bit.  Endianness changes the order in which bytes are used for multi-byte things like integers.

Comment: @UKMonkey I got it thanks! The Tow PCs I am testing on are identical in term of hardware. Furthermore, I tested on an Ubuntu VM inside the Windows. The Ubuntu VM works while the Windows Host did not.

Comment: Please show the data that you're tranferring (and how). This is bound to be the issue. We cannot give constructive solutions in the absense of these details